# Half of half output

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am not getting second line of output 
which must be "nk"
basically i want to give output of half of input and even as well
like in mayank it will make it half l/2 
on entering mayank and nikhil i should get the even index "my"& "ny"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, l, temp, j, i;
    cin >> n;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    char a[n][100];
    while (i < n) {
        cin >> a[i];
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        l = strlen(a[i]);
        while (j < l / 2) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                cout << a[i][j];
            }
            j = j + 2;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not upload images of code. Rather, copy-paste the code

Comment: `char a[n][100];` isnt' standard c++. Consider using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Please explain in more detail, what you are trying to achieve. At the moment I do not really understand your question....

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. From what i understand, you want to split a string in half (?) and then do something with it.

Comment: first it asks about the no of string you are entering,then it runs the program the number of test cases, for which i want to achieve all even even characters in each string ,and it should take only half of the string for this , for ex   2  mayank nikhil  give my ny seperated by a newline.

Comment: @Mayanktiwari So you want to read N strings and for every one print only the first half?

Comment: yes ,and from that only even index output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure about what exactly you are trying to do. But here is your code, made to print characters of even index, only up to the first half of each string.
Please note that in order to have a dynamic array you need to use either `malloc()` (C style) or `new` (C++ style).

I have used malloc in this example to keep it as close to your original code as possible, note that the only "C++" in this code is `cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, l, temp, j, i;
    cin >> n;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    char **a = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i]=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    }
    i=0;
    while (i < n) {
    cin >> a[i];
    i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(a[i])/2;j++)
        {
            if(j%2==0)
            {
                cout << a[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i understood it clearly .

Comment: Now on submitting my code i get SIGSEGV ERROR

Comment: @Mayanktiwari If you are getting segmentation faults, it probably means pointer problems or out of bounds index on an array. What exactly are you getting ? Maybe it's a subject for another question.